# R: ggplot ylim doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I am trying to change the ylim in a plot. But as soon as I change it, the plot vanishes. I am not able to figure out the reason. Can someone help me to root cause the issue?

```
>df<-data.frame(Category=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "D", "C"), Setup=c("X", "Y"), Gain=c(1.4, 1.45, 1.43, 1.48, 1.33, 1.37, 1.04, 1.09))
>p<-ggplot( df, aes(Setup, Gain)) + ylim(0.9, 1.25) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap( "Category", ncol=2 )
```

When I remove the ylim(), the above code works but with `ylim` it doesn't work. Any idea what's the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace `ylim(0.9, 1.25)` with

```
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.9, 1.25))
```

The function `ylim` also influences which data points are used for plotting. In contrast, `coord_cartesian` will not change the underlying data.

The complete command:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Setup, Gain)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.9, 1.25)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap("Category", ncol = 2)
```

[image]

The `ylim` approach will result in the following data:

```
df[df$Gain >= 0.9 & df$Gain <= 1.25, ]

  Category Setup Gain
7        D     X 1.04
8        C     Y 1.09
```

Furthermore, it will remove all bars since they start at `0`.

Comment: This works. But what's the issue with ylim? What is coord_cartesian doing?

Comment: @RachitAgrawal `ylim` will also change to underlying data and remove all values outside the specified range.

Comment: I had tried ylim(0.5, 1.5) as well in which all data points come in the range. Even in that case it was not working.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal This is because your bars start at `0`.

Comment: How can I change the color of these bars. Adding `fill` and `scale_fill_brewer` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @RachitAgrawal Should all bars have the same color?

Comment: No, I want different colors for "X" and "Y".

Comment: @RachitAgrawal Add `fill = Setup` to the `aes` of `ggplot`.